# “Partial application” for template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, boost-mpl

I have the following “main” template:

```
template <
        template <typename> class S
    > struct TT { /*...*/ };
```

and the template I want to use with `TT`:

```
template <int N, typename T> struct S1 {};
```

In particular, I want to use something like

```
TT< S1<5> > t2; // "Invalid template arguments" here
```

It is a kind of partial application for templates. I know that Boost.MPL involves this kind of stuff. The problem is that I already have some code using TT and templates like

```
template <typename T> struct S2 {}; // S3, S4…
```

which are fed to TT.

So the question is: how can I use `S1` with `TT` with smallest modifications to existing code. If it is mandatory to use Boost.MPL please show me most suitable solution.

Comment: is `template <class S> struct TT { /*...*/ };` not an option?

Comment: `TT< S1<5> > t2;` you are missing the second argument to S1. Master of the obvious over and out.

Comment: @Mooing Thanks, I have already considered this option, but TT really have internal typedef (say P) which is really an “implementation detail” and TT specifies S with P. At this point I can't see how can I make TT accept type instead of template with at least one type parameter.

Comment: @AJG85 obviously supplying second argument won't make this compile as well — so the essence of question…

Comment: @Artem Pelenitsyn: Refer to Nawaz's answer the nested template is not necessary. You could add a defaulted `int` argument to `S11` template and pass it through the wrapper as well if needed.

Comment: @AJG85: He wants the ability to supply int-argument as well. Just see my solution!

Comment: @Nawaz: Wrap the wrapper ... even better!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a class template deriving from `S1` as:

```
template <typename T> 
struct S11 : S1<5,T>
{
};
```

And then use `S11`, instead of `S1` as:

```
TT< S11> t2;  //it is as if TT< S1<5> > t2
```

Working code : http://ideone.com/y2s7n

---

Reading your comment, it seems you need this:

```
template<int N>
struct Magic
{
   template <typename T> 
   struct S11 : S1<N,T>
   {
   };
};

//Usage
TT<Magic<5>::S11> t2;
```

Magic Demo : http://ideone.com/4yxvK

Answer (score 3):

you can also write a generic partial application facility:

```cpp
template <template <typename ...> class TT, typename... Args>
struct Apply
{
    template <typename... Rest>
    struct T : TT < Args..., Rest... >
    {
    };
};
```

or like this if you want the result time of the application to be the original template's specializations instead of a derived class (of a derived class, etc.):

```cpp
template <template <typename ...> class TT, typename... Args>
struct Apply
{
    template <typename... Rest>
    struct _T  
    { 
        typedef TT < Args..., Rest... > type;
    };

    template <typename... Rest>
    using T = typename _T < Rest... >::type ;
};
```